# Redirect to login page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, authentication

I am new to wordpress. I am running wordpress setup on `http://localhost/wordpress/`. I am facing two problems right now:

- Only the logged in users can access the site. So, I am trying to redirect the user from home page to login page using the following code which is somehow isn't working:

> Path: `wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/header.php`

```
        <?php
            if(get_permalink() != wp_login_url() && !is_user_logged_in()){
                wp_redirect( wp_login_url() ); exit;
            }
        ?>
```

Since the above code wasn't working, I tried to move on by letting the user to login manually by clicking on the `login` button. Here is the working code:

```
<?php
    if(get_permalink() != wp_login_url() && !is_user_logged_in()){
        // wp_redirect( wp_login_url() ); exit;
?>
        <a href="<?php echo wp_login_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="Login">Login</a>
<?php
    }
?>
```

- From above code, when user clicked on login  he was redirected to login page and When the user is logs in, the page is redirecting to wordpress admin i.e `wp-admin` instead of home page i.e `http://localhost/wordpress`.

#### What I am trying to do is:

- Redirect the user from home page to login page, if the user isn't logged in.
- And then redirect the user from login page to home page instead of wp-admin, when user logs in.

Answer (score 6):

To redirect the user from homepage to login page, you can use Wordpress function
is_user_logged_in,

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

```php
if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
    wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
}
```

To redirect user on homepage rather Dashboard, you can follow already posted solution on Stack overflow.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-can-i-redirect-users-to-the-front-page-after-log-in

Answer (score 4):

Here are a set of codes that you'll need:

- You need to redirect users from wp-admin to the home page but make sure you do not redirect Ajax requests as well.
- Disable admin bar for specific user roles

--

```
//Redirect user to the home page when they try to access admin panel while allowing Ajax requests.
function block_admin_access_for_subs()
{
    // Restrict backend access for subscribers
    if( is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX') && (current_user_can('subscriber')) ){
        wp_redirect(home_url());
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('init', 'block_admin_access_for_subs');

//Disable admin bar for specific user roles
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar_for_subs');
function remove_admin_bar_for_subs() {
    if (current_user_can('subscriber') && !is_admin()) {
        show_admin_bar(false);
    }
}
```

Add below code in the template where you want a user to be redirected to login page.

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
       auth_redirect();
}
```

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/auth_redirect

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like this by passing a url

```
<?php
        if(get_permalink() != wp_login_url() && !is_user_logged_in()){
            wp_redirect( wp_login_url($redirect) ); exit;
        }
    ?>
```

and your redirect.. must be an absolute..

```
$redirect = site_url().'/login';
```

or whatever the url u choose.